# Diagnose 400 error on IIS 7.5

Tags: wcf, http, iis, http-status-code-400

I'm running IIS 7.5 on Windows 2008 R2 Server. The client receives the following error from a WCF service when trying to send a request to it:

> The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

The request isn't logged in the IIS logs and no useful information is coming from failed request tracing. There's nothing in the event log and WCF tracing yields nothing. From this, I surmise that the request is being intercepted by http.sys and never even gets to IIS or the application. However, I am not seeing anything in the httperr log. I do see other unrelated log entries in there. Is there something further I need to do to ensure that the http request is logged?

(For the record, the service is running in a different environment with the same configuration, so I believe it's set up properly. I'd like to get a positive ID on the problem before I go with trial and error.)

Comment: Do you get anything useful in a WCF trace generated on the client side - e.g. does the request look sane?

Comment: Did not get anything in WCF trace whatsoever. :(

Comment: Learn what is HTTP.sys error logging and it should be recorded there.